# design high volume MSMQ

Tags: msmq, netmsmqbinding, msmq-wcf

We have many communication servers sending data packets. We would like to store these data packets coming from these server programs in MSMQ until an updater will process them. Data loss has been a concern and we would like to not lose any data packet coming from these server programs and want an efficient and performant solution.

What will be the best design approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are two basic things you need to do to get started. First, you'll want to modify the default installation to move the storage location to a drive that is mirrored and/or is not the same as the one that the operating system boots from on that server. Also you'll want to ensure there is enough space there to hold messages as they are queued, depending on the volume you're contemplating. [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2009/02/09/changing-the-msmq-storage-location.aspx) article covers that.

Second, you'll want to use transactions and journaling to ensure reliability. This is both a programming and infrastructure issue, so you can start by looking at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978430.aspx) article, and then following up with a general guide on how to program against MSMQ correctly. [This](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/klaus_salchner/MSMQ11292005035019AM/MSMQ.aspx) for example is a good starting point if you've never used MSMQ, although it's fairly basic. If you're going to use MSMQ as a binding/transport for WCF then you have the plumbing part pretty much covered; it's just a matter of configuring your services to handle the volume and traffic you think you're going to see.

Comment: Many thanks for the design idea. I would like to go with WCF and MSMQ setting up Transaction queue and Journal queue. We have a number of applications sending data packets. Should my WCF client be configured to listen on one port for the data packets coming from these applications ? Will that be a overhead . I want to take data packets and write them to queue. Again volume is high ( million data packets per day) What is the best way ? Any sample code I can look at ? Is WCF good for this ? Thanks

Comment: There is a _lot_ of information out there, just searching Google for 'configure wcf msmq' yields a bunch of useful articles. How you go about this depends on your particular situation; I'd suggest reading up as much as you can and then making a decision. Your volume doesn't seem like it will be a problem. WCF and MSMQ are highly performant, assuming they are configured correctly.

Comment: Thanks . I will search and find out more.

Answer (score 0):

> We have many communication servers sending data packets.

When storing 'data packets', I would recommend writing `[Serializable]` .NET objects to WCF, mainly because WCF can read/write them transparently to MSMQ. This will be easier to work with, but if your data packets are say TCP/IP or binary packets, you will need to turn on 'Ordering', to ensure they go into the queue in the exact order they were placed.

MSMQ also has sessions, so if you want to group items together this is possible. WCF does not make this guarantee. You will need to write custom code for this, but it is only a case of assigning a unique ID to each message in a particular session.

> Data loss has been a concern and we would like to not lose any data packet coming from these server programs

MSMQ can persist the data to disk, so if a server goes down, its queue is preserved. MSMQ can hold the queue in memory, which is more efficient but crashes/restarts will not retain the queue information.

> and want an efficient( good performance )

MSMQ is fairly performant. The persistence to disk has a small overhead, but only due to the disk write. If performance includes multi-threading, MSMQ does not offer this feature as the queue is sequential, so must be processed in order. But this is typical of queue technologies.

MSMQ also have 4MB max message size, so keep in mind what you want to send across the network.

The only other thing is that MSMQ is not massively scalable. Its primary goal is guaranteed delivery. If you post *millions* of packets, they will get to their destination, but MSMQ does have a finite ability to push the messages to other machines. It operates a ThreadPool-like system, so it will not scale if this is also a requirement.

I have also added info to the #msmq-wcf wiki with a basic example of writing data.